# Does Ubuntu for windows have GPU support?

Tags: gpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6

I'm wondering if I could get Pytorch running on this version on Ubuntu without needing to dual boot - anyone have more info on this?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly the same reason why I also was wondering what the state of the GPU support was! :D

Answer (score 11):

Not yet, though it is [the most-requested feature on our UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/16108045-opencl-cuda-gpu-support) ;)

Comment: that link is now 