# "ubuntu-drivers devices" always returns nothing in Ubuntu on Windows (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, windows-10

I was following [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) to install GPU driver for my Nvidia GTX 1070 graphic card on my Alienware laptop. To check the recommended driver version, I used this command:

`ubuntu-drivers devices`

and also tried this:

`sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`

But both gave me nothing in return, like this:

```
george@DESKTOP:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
george@DESKTOP:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
[sudo] password for george:
george@DESKTOP:~$
```

Here are the things I've tried:

- Disabled secure boot as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050423/cannot-get-nvidia-graphics-card-to-work-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
- `sudo apt install nvidia-settings`

Could this be a Windows Subsystem for Linux specific issue? Maybe Ubuntu doesn't have enough privilege on Windows? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Ubuntu for windows have GPU support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935735/does-ubuntu-for-windows-have-gpu-support)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that GPU is not supported through Windows Subsystem for Linux yet:

[Does Ubuntu for windows have GPU support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935735/does-ubuntu-for-windows-have-gpu-support)